# Force change encoding on Safari with web server code

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, safari

I am having a very strange problem which I have been banging my head at for quite some time now.

I have been trying to force an encoding change in Safari by using the following.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

The problem is that Safari doesn't seem to care at all and uses a different encoding. (All other browsers comply perfectly)

Is there any way to force Safari to cooperate with the encoding that I set?

I get strange characters like this: â€˜

Showing up all over my website.

If I manually change the Safari encoding from 'default' to Unicode (UTF-8) all of them disappear and the website works perfectly.

I tried researching the problem, and all I could find was more people talking about this problem rather than any solutions so hopefully StackOverflow can produce some helpful answers.

I can show example for those that request it.

Comment: STRANGE: I can modify encoding on Safari if I set the header in PHP... Why not HTML?

Comment: Safari is terrible...

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not care what you specify in your HTML code. Safari is poorly cooperating browser and likes to operate in its own unique way.

You can ONLY modify the encoding type by modifying it in the header itself.

This can be done at the web server in the NGINX configuration or via a PHP script.

Comment: I hope this helps some developers banging their head when the problem isn't their code, but rather Safari's.